# Create formatter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, autohotkey, vscode-extensions

When I try to auto indent my .ahk files, I get "There is no formatter for 'ahk'-files installed." How can I create a rudimentary formatter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual studio code AutoHotkey indentation and formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774489/visual-studio-code-autohotkey-indentation-and-formatting)

Comment: As the title states, this question is about how to create a formatter.

Answer (score 5):

The approach is the same like for any other language/file specific extensions in vscode: you have to create an extension and register the providers for the features you want to support, e.g. references provider, symbol provider etc. In your case you have to implement a formatting provider, [see here how I did it](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/frontend/FormattingProvider.ts) in my extension. In order use it in vscode you have to [register it](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/ExtensionHost.ts#L138) in your main extension file. That looks like:

```
context.subscriptions.push(languages.registerDocumentRangeFormattingEditProvider(ANTLR, new AntlrFormattingProvider(backend)));
```

I recommend reading up about how to create an extension for vscode before you actually start the formatting provider. Here's a good description of the first steps: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

Comment: Can you update the lines pointed by your register code?

Comment: @R.Gurung Updated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - at time of writing, this just doesn't exist for VS Code.

The closest you'd get is to keep an eye on the main autohotkey extension for VS Code here:

https://github.com/stef-levesque/vscode-autohotkey

It may be worth putting a request in on that github repository requesting formatting features be added to the extension.